# What exactly is done with cv2.resize?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My colleague and I were importing data from a thermal camera using this Python script:

```
      try:
    while True:
      data = q.get(True, 500)
      if data is None:
        break
         data = cv2.resize(data[:,:], (80, 60))
#          f.write(data)
      minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(data)

#          img = raw_to_8bit(data)
      np.savetxt("uvc-capture-file.txt",np.array(data))
#         f.write(" ")
      display_temperature(img, minVal, minLoc, (255, 0, 0))
      display_temperature(img, maxVal, maxLoc, (0, 0, 255))
      cv2.imshow('Lepton 2.5 Radiometry', img)
      cv2.waitKey(1)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  finally:
    libuvc.uvc_stop_streaming(devh)
    f.close()
  print "done"
finally:
  libuvc.uvc_unref_device(dev)
finally:
libuvc.uvc_exit(ctx)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Everything works, but in the line `data = cv2.resize(data[:,:], (80, 60))` we changed the resize from 640, 480. We aren't sure why the script was originally that, but when we ran it, it gave us a nice text document with 640x480 numbers in a matrix.

The only issue is that the thermal sensor only collects data from 80x60 area. Where is it getting the "filler" numbers from? The script works the same way with 80x60, but instead of giving us a text document with a 640x480 matrix of numbers, it gave us one that was 80x60. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the API documentation of cv2.resize](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation)), your 640x480 matrix is being interpolated from whatever numbers are available in the data matrix you passed in. Unless you need your original 80x60 data "blown up" to some specific format, you should be able to skip this line/step without loss of information.